# How to check if a string contains only specific characters in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I want my string only have (a-zA-Z0-9@.-_) but when using this code:

```
import re
e='p12/5@gmail.com'
p=re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z0-9@.-_]')
for ele in e:
    if bool(p.search(ele)):
        print('okay')
    else:
        print('n')
```

it prints 'okay' but I expect to print 'n' because my string(e) contains '/' and I didn't declare it on my regex.
what should I do?
I also used `re.match` and didn't help me either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here. First `.` and `-` are meta-characters, and need to escaped with a `\`. Second, you don't really need the loop here - add a `*` to indicate any number of these characters, and qualify the regex between `^` and `$` to signify the entire string needs to be made up of these characters:

```py
import re
e = 'p12/5@gmail.com'
p = re.compile(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9@\.\-_]*$')

if p.match(e):
    print('okay')
else:
    print('n')
```

Comment: Oh I didn't know about meta-characters. anything other than alphabets and numbers is meta-character?

Comment: @parsap1378 You can find a full list with explanations about all the special characters in `re`'s documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html